# Required to post comments as answers

Tags: discussion, comments, privileges

Due to the restrictions on posting comments, I am often forced into adding an answer and stating that I am unable to add comments. (Here is an example of an 'answer' that is more a comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/5miz0w254vdok66/Screenshot_2014-10-21-21-11-38.png?dl=0)

Now the theory behind the restrictions on comments is well and good, however many users will not mark an answer as correct, or mark it up- once they get their answer they're happy. Understanding that my 'answers' are never intended as answers, more comments ( thus marking it up or correct is irrelevant) . I'd just like to see the ability to allow me to comment on a question.

I know this'll fall under "off topic", but I would really appreciate anyone advising me of an alternative to adding comments as answer.

Comment: Only way you can achieve it is by having some reputation...Earn it..

Comment: nobalG, valid point however I do find it quite difficult!

Comment: I saw you answering quite a lot of Android questions recently. While you stated that it should be a comment, I don't think so. Some of your "comments" are as good as stand-alone answers themselves. I also that you have quite participation on Ask Ubuntu, so I guess you already understand how SE sites works (rep, privilege, etc). I also observe that this site doesn't have much activity, hence the slowness in getting rep. But don't give up! I upvoted some of your answers that I believe is correct. And lastly, this post should have been posted on [meta] instead, just in case you don't know :)

Comment: [Just this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) and [Why it is there](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated some of your comments are good as answers in their own right. I'm only adding this as it is something I **still** do. I'm not sure if it's lack of confidence, or some of the HUGE answers to big questions I've read here.

Don't forget answers are fluid things, you can always edit and amend them. People will comment on your answers, and you can always factor that in. You and I need to just start posting answers more often!

Sometimes an answer is just "No you can't" like my [recent answer here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/86166/how-do-you-leave-a-review-on-the-google-play-store-without-a-google-account) and that's about it. But that is the actual, correct answer!

A good rule I use is try not to recommend the 'nuclear option' as your first advice, it happens a fair bit. My SMS is not sending, factory reset. The brightness is too low, Factory Reset!

This answer I'm writing here is a good example of something that borders on a comment, but in the spirit of things I'm adding it as an answer!

Answer (score 1):

Upon discussion of this topic, I have reviewed the policies in place, attempted to refine my 'answers'. Due to the help of the community I now have earned the privilege of adding comments.

Upon reviewing my current answers, I found by adding more relevant information, whilst possibly just personal experience, I have been able to add weight to my answers.